# Multi line plot and re-label legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

1) Why are lines so dense?

In the dataset the time is by hour, if time was by day would it make a difference. I would like to see a line chart for each host.

2) How can I re-label the legend from count to host?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
df.groupby('host').plot(x='time', y='count',ax=ax, legend=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this are two actually two questions in one post. Also please try to provide some (automated test) data and a minimal complete working example. Cheers

Comment: It would be great if you could add small database with some data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are plotting hourly data of more than 6 months. That's ~4k data points, of course it is dense. Daily data would be better, although it's still going to be dense.
2. There are a couple of options:

You could either use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/)

```
import seaborn as sns
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
sns.lineplot(x='time', y='count', ax=ax, hue='host')
```

Or do a loop on `groupby`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
for h, d in df.groupby('host'):
    d.plot(x='time', y='count', ax=ax, label=h)
```

Comment: I changed the dataset to weekly and the graph looks better and the loop on groupby is perfect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ad 2) just add `label='name'` as parameter, i.e:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
df.groupby('host').plot(x='time', y='count',ax=ax, legend=True, label='host')
```